# How can I represent a Data Frame on my website?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, flask

I’m building a web application using Flask that allows users to upload datasets up to 100mb in size. I’m using NumPy and Pandas to do the data wrangling. I need to be able to display the users data frame— however, the data frame itself will not be interactive. Any suggestions on how I can display the data? It would be nice to display the data in a Juypter Notebook fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `df.to_html()`. 
Then output the string to your web application as a html table.

Reference here:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html